# Visual Studio 2019 Application Arguments for Dotnetcore function

Tags: visual-studio

I have build a donetcore function inside VS 2019 which failes without any hint

It mentions during start
**For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.**

But every application argument is causing a
Error: **unknown argument --verbose**

How could I use arguments for better debugging ?

[image: Arguments]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is the proper place to pass command line arguments.

You just have to add `start` before `--verbose`, like so:

```
start --verbose
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `--verbose` flag to the `commandLineArgs` property in the `Functions` object in the launchsettings.json file:

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "Functions": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "commandLineArgs": "--port 7239 --verbose"
    }
  }
}
```

If you use the 'properties' page for the project file when using Visual Studio, as mentioned in another answer, it will add this for you into the  launchsettings.json file. If using an IDE like VSCode, then edit the file yourself.

Comment: already answered and solved three years ago

Comment: This answer is a valid alternative to configuring the same command line arg via the IDE gui. It worked for my VS2022 project 5 minutes. The console window is now full of extra details showing how my Function App boots up but alas no info on why my class based Activity function is not identified.